# How do I find the PMF of X when X is the number of flips of a fair coin that are required to observe the same face on consecutive flips?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, functions, statistical-inference

How do I find the PMF of $X$ when $X$ equals number of flips of a fair coin that are required to observe the same face on consecutive flips?

The hint was to draw some sort of a tree diagram, but I'm not quite sure as to how it helps. I know that $P(X=x)=\sum(f(x))$, but I don't even know where to start for this particular question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of tosses required. It is clear that $X$ must be $\ge 2$.

In order for $n$ to be the first place where we observe two consecutive identical flips, (i) heads and tails must alternate in the first $n-1$ tosses, **and** (ii) the $n$-th toss must match the $(n-1)$-th toss.

The probability of alternation in the first $n-1$ tosses is $2\cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. For we can get alternation in $2$ ways: HTHTHT$\dots$ or THTHTH$\dots$.  So our required probability is $2\cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

**Another way:** *After the first toss*, the probability of "success" each time is $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus the number of tosses required is $1$ more than the number of trials until the first success, where the probability of success is $\frac{1}{2}$.

It follows that $X=1+Y$, where $Y$ has geometric distribution with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $\Pr(X=n)=\Pr(Y=n-1)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: I see now. It makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.